# Ajax Load and inject issue in footer

Tags: jquery

I am putting together an ajax shopping cart and I started today thinking I was going to get something simple done...dynamic year in the copyright. No sweat just add a span with an id of year and use jquery to replace the text in said span. Well...sometimes it just isn't easy.

My problem is this: I am loading the footer content dynamically from another file and then changing the year:

```
$('#footer').load('common.html #footerContent');

$("#copyYear").html( (new Date).getFullYear() );
```

I think that is where the problem lies...in the asynchronous loading?

I have played with it for far too long and am now here to beg for help.

I appreciate it a lot!

The site is at http://chainery.comoj.com

Thank you,
Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that is where the problem lies...in the asynchronous loading?

Yes, probably `#copyYear` doesn't exist in the DOM at the moment you are trying to set its html. So you could perform this operation inside the AJAX success callback:

```
$('#footer').load('common.html #footerContent', function() {
    $('#copyYear').html( (new Date).getFullYear() );
});
```

Comment: Exactly it! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the date **after** the content is loaded.

```
$('#footer').load('common.html #footerContent', function(){ 
    $("#copyYear").html( (new Date).getFullYear() );
);
```